# error: const method that returns an array of pointers by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constants, return-by-reference

```cpp
class Board{
private:
    Shape shapes[100];
    Tile* tiles[16];
public:
    const Shape (&getShapes() const)[100]{return shapes;}; // (1) 
    const Tile* (&getTiles() const)[16]{return tiles;}; // (2)
};
```

I made this class called `Board` that has two methods returning an array by reference.

Method (2) reports an error:

> qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "const Tile *(&)[16]" to initializer of type "Tile *const [16]"

I fixed this error by writing `const` to the return type in method (1), but it doesn't work for method (2).

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Use `std::array` and all your problems go away.

Comment: You const qualified the pointed-to type, but you need to const qualify the pointer type. `Tile* const (&getTiles() const)[16]{return tiles;};`. const to `Tile` is possible, but optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element type of this array

```
 Tile* tiles[16]
```

is `Tile *`. As the member function is a constant member function then the function should return the array by reference with constant elements. That is it should be declared like

```
Tile* const (&getTiles() const)[16]{return tiles;}
```

That is you may not assign new values to the pointers stored in the array.